# Insert text into file

Tags: command-line, sed

I'm trying to insert some text into a file on a specific line which I have managed to do with sed the below being inserted into line 34 of the txt file.

```
sed -i "34i some text" name_of_file.txt
```

The above works fine, but now I need to insert some text with quotes in it.

```
"some text"
```

so trying:

```
sed -i "34i "some text"" name_of_file.txt
```

However the quotes don't write to the file. Anyone able to help me with this, or is there something else I can use that will work with quotation marks and allow me to specify the line to insert them into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to *quote* the quotes using the backslash "\":

```
sed -i "34i \"some text\"" name_of_file.txt
```

Comment: Changing the outer quotes to single-quotes would work too `sed -i '34i "some text"'`

Answer (score 1):

To use double quotes, encase the whole text with single-quotes:

```
sed -i '34i "some text"' name_of_file.txt
```